# Alteração em massa no MYSQL

Tags: mysql, query

Oi, pessoal, td certo?

Tenho um banco no mysql e preciso fazer uma alteração em massa, tem como?

Quero alterar todos os registros da coluna "show_address" da tabela ptv_osrs_properties para "1".

Tenho uns 300 registros, consigo fazer isso em massa de uma só vez?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tenho certeza se entendi direito, mas se você quer atualizar todos os registros da tabela, basta fazer um update:

```
update ptv_osrs_properties set show_address = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Minha sugestão update sem where

```
UPDATE ptv_osrs_properties 
SET show_address = '1'
```